# Couldn't install npm because of a node-pre-gyp error

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to run a downloaded ionic template in my PC using Visual Studio Code IDE, But i get the below error when i try to run `npm install`

```
> grpc@1.20.0 install C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and node@12.14.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.4.29613.14) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.960) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\project\\Template-Ionic\\ionic-starter-master\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\project\\Template-Ionic\\ionic-starter-master\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=C:\\Python27\\python.exe" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\project\\Template-Ionic\\ionic-starter-master\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\project\Template-Ionic\ionic-starter-master\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm WARN videogular2@6.4.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-09T20_01_03_925Z-debug.log
```

I have tried many stack overflow solutions and still end up with the same error,'
Solutions i tried 
[NPM Install Error - Node-Pre-Gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513644/npm-install-error-node-pre-gyp)

[Npm install not installing because of node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750317/npm-install-not-installing-because-of-node-gyp/57763427#57763427)

[Npm install not installing because of node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750317/npm-install-not-installing-because-of-node-gyp/57763427#57763427)

Can anyone help me out

*Note if it's helpful, I tried running a basic ionic template and it worked*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common cause of the error message "Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and node@12.14.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)" shown in that error output is that the version of Node you are using is too new for the version of grpc that you are installing. So you should either update to a newer version of grpc or use an older version of Node.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to fix these errors on a handful of different Windows computers with a few steps. I haven't yet tested which are necessary and which are not

1. Install Node.js in Windows Terminals => run npm i => Get the error
2. Install Visual Studio, install C++ Desktop environment, find where it offers you optional packages, install the relevant packages (the ones selected) [C++ Desktop packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpx0f.png)
3. Install Python(s) after these steps (2.7.17 and 3.8.1); It will give you the [Repair] Option which worked fine, make sure to add to PATH
4. Open Windows Powershell **as Administrator** (it will still have issues in regular term)
5. in the Admin Powershell => npm i => builds correctly and can be run from anywhere now

Comment: Is this only for Windows boxes?

Comment: @Nelles as far as I know, this problem only affects Windows yeah. Fairly certain you only need the system-wide Python install to repair it.